# How to set the values of the columns of the selectedRows in AgGrid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

const selectedRows: any[] = gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows()[0];

Here selectedRows is the row that I have selected.(In AgGrid it is thr row which is checked). 
In this case the selectedRows is the first row that I have selected.

Also the some of the column  of the AgGrid will have the type of BOProperty.
To be more precise BOProperty is a model which has a property called defaultvalue.

How can I set the value of a particular column in this row which has "boProperty.defaultValue!==undefined" ?
(boProperty is of type BOProperty and the value is obtained from webmodules)
boprpoperty.defaultValue already has some value.

Now if the default value is defined then when I copy the selectedRows, the new Row should have the column value as default value.

Can somebody help ?

Comment: Can you please add some code snippet or some expected output?

Answer (score 0):

The wording of the detail of your question doesn't really make any sense to me, but in answer to what I assume to be the basic question "how do I update the data in selected rows in AgGrid?",

You have a an array of data that bind to the grid via it's 'rowData' property.
To update the data in the grid, you need to update your array of data, and then that will be reflected in the grid.

Actually, you need to replace your array with a new array that has the updated data, but that's very easy to do. I'll explain below.

Step one - get the selected rows from the grid using the grid api's `getSelectedRows()` function.

Step two - for each row returned by `getSelectedRows()`,  find the corresponding row in your rowData, and update it however you wish.

Step three - trigger the change in the grid by replacing your array with a new array instance, e.g. `this.rowData = [...this.rowData];`

This is the "brute-force" way of doing it - there are better ways to produce the new array, like mapping the original array.